# how can i modify a value in list<t>?

Tags: c#

```
    class SomeClass
    {

        private struct PhraseInfo
        {
            public int Start;
            public int Length;
        }

...

        private void SomeMethod(...)
        {
            List<PhraseInfo> posesBracket = new List<PhraseInfo>();
            posesBracket.Add(new PhraseInfo());
            posesBracket[0].Start = 10;
        }
```

of cause, posesBracket[0].start=10; occur compiler error CS1612 : "Cannot modify the return value of 'expression' because it is not a variable"

how can i modify a value in list?

Comment: `start` should be written with an upper-case `S`, but that doesn't quite match the error you're getting. And `struct` is probably not a valid return type for a method.

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `posesBracket[0].Start=10;` (Capital S in Start)?

Comment: oh sorry. that was mistyping but that is a not a point.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wydkhw2c.aspx

Comment: The fundamental problem is that you have a mutable value type. Either make the mutable type a class type, or make the value type immutable. You are trying to treat a mutable value type as though it is a reference type, and discovering the hard way that value types are *copied by value, not by reference*. That's why they're called "value types".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that PhraseInfo is a value type, so the this[] method will return a value, not a reference, to solve it, do this:

```
PhraseInfo pi = posesBracket[0];
pi.Start = 10;
posesBracket[0] = pi;
```

Comment: thanks. but it's a messy. so i'll declare a initializer of the PhraseInfo.

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = posesBracket[0];
temp.Start = 10;
posesBracket[0] = temp;
```

Comment: no. it didn't work. the temp is a value type. the temp is not the pointer of the posesBracket[0].

Comment: and... where I've made mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a struct defined as a method. And as they say, you need the reference to change values. So it goes like this:

```
class SomeClass
    {

        private struct PhraseInfo
        {
            public int Start;
            public int Length;
        }

        private void somemethod()
        {
            List<PhraseInfo> posesBracket = new List<PhraseInfo>();
            posesBracket.Add(new PhraseInfo());
            PhraseInfo pi = posesBracket[0];
            pi.Start = 10;
            posesBracket[0] = pi;
        }
    }
```

Comment: no. it didn't work. the temp is a value type. the temp is not the pointer of the posesBracket[0].

Comment: i saw. posesBracket[0] = pi;. thanks. it was solved for your help.